# Getting started with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm just starting to dip my toes in the water with Selenium and trying to make it work
my code is the following:

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\operadriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.opera(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

as simple as this code is I'm already having errors...

the error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(my user)\PycharmProjects\selenium\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.opera(PATH)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any help is appreciated,and sorry if the question is dumb lol

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

is because webdriver.opera is not a function, but is actually an object.
You have not included your import statements here, but I would recommend you to try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\operadriver.exe"
web_driver = webdriver.Opera(driver_path)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

Note: I also changed your path to a raw string, as you're on Windows and the backslash might break in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation?

```
from selenium.webdriver.opera.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "/path/to/opera.exe"
driver = webdriver.Opera(options=options, executable_path=PATH)
```

Comment: I swear I was looking trough the documentation for half an hour looking for this,thanks man